# Better to use block RAM or distributed RAM?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, ram

Now I am working on a project where I am sending over bytes from master to slave via i2c using fpgas. Now In my slave I want to store data coming in and I plan to have between 3-5 arrays like the following each with different indices ranging from 0 to 71 :

```
type array1 is array(0 to 49) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

type array2 is array(0 to 23) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

type array3 is array(0 to 71) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
```

Been doing some research and I understand that there for xilinx there are two different types of ram known as Block and Distributed but that distributed should be used for small sized memories. Now my question is if I use these types of arrays is it small enough to use distributed? Or is it better to just go for Block?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on you design and the specific FPGA you are using.
The synthesis tool can often decide for you what is the best.
Only, if you want the tool to be able to decide for you, you have to implement it in a way that it can be implemented as both. For Xilinx FPGA's you can for instance reference [The sysnthesis user guide](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2016_4/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf), which describes correct VHDL syntax in "RAM HDL Coding Techniques".
I.e. it is not possible to access multiple entries at the same time (other than in a dual-port RAM fashion). And you require a certain amount of clock cycles for data store and/or retrieval.

Some more links:

- [Block and distributed RAM's on Xilinx FPGA's](http://vhdlguru.blogspot.nl/2011/01/block-and-distributed-rams-on-xilinx.html)
- [Block RAM or Distributed RAM](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/Block-RAM-or-Distributed-RAM/td-p/39779)
- [Inferring Block RAM vs. Distributed RAM in XST and Precision](http://www.dilloneng.com/inferring-block-ram-vs-distributed-ram-in-xst-and-precision.html#/)
- [Block vs Distributed RAM](http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=29421)

Answer (score 1):

In your case it doesn't really matter - distributed or block memory. It's probably a very low-speed design that needs few hundred bits of memory.

Answer (score 0):

> Now my question is if I use these types of arrays is it small enough to use distributed?

This depends on the specific FPGA you are using and the mode in which you want to use it. For example, a 7 series device will provide a number of different access configurations (single, dual, quad), which have different memory configurations (eg. A single slice can potentially provide a 256 x 1-bit, single port RAM).

Based on the examples you provide, you could potentially fit one of your arrays in distributed RAM, with the remainder requiring multiple DRAMs or a single BRAM. It is worth noting that if you did use a mix of DRAM/BRAM, you need to be aware of the read semantics of DRAM (async, versus sync for BRAM), which you would need to account for.

If you have BRAMs available on the device, and they aren't being used, I would just use them in preference to DRAM (but maybe that's just me).